# Removing trailing slash in a String

Tags: dart, flutter

**Some users type `https://google.com/` and some users type `https://google.com`**

How to check If user type with slash or not? If user type with a slash How to remove slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'https://google.com/';
if (str.endsWith('/')) str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you re doing lots of string manipulations you can use a sanitize package https://pub.dev/documentation/validators/latest/sanitizers/sanitizers-library.html, in your case it would be `rtrim(str, ' /')`